# C# getting values from specific group

Tags: c#, list

How do I get all values in a list starting at index 1 and everything after?

```
list.Split(' ')[1:]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Linq:

```
var l = list.Split(' ').Skip(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the LINQ [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) extension method:

```
list.Split(' ').Skip(1)
```

If you want the result as a list you need to use the extension method `ToList` too.

```
list.Split(' ').Skip(1).ToList()
```

Worth to note is that there is also a [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) extension method that takes the `n` next items in the sequence. Usually used like this

```
list.Split(' ').Skip(n*pageSize).Take(pageSize)
```